Proxy server(s) were detected or fingerprinted
Disable the 'TRACE' method on the proxy servers, as well as the origin web/application
server.
Disable the 'OPTIONS' method on the proxy servers, as well as the origin web/application
server, if it is not required for other purposes, such as 'CORS' (Cross Origin Resource
Sharing).
I need my application to deny such requests instead of disabling these methods, how can I do that in my web application?

https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask
